# Aristotelian realism of universals

Tags: realism, universals

I'm trying to understand this realism. There are universals that exist in particulars and they are all identical. Is this Identity a numerical identity? i.e. are these universals one and the same thing? Or are they distinct but indiscernible things?

Comment: "There are universals that exist in particulars and they are all identical." On what sense? Maybe universals are abstractions and are not **in**...

Comment: I'm talking about aristotelian realism where universals exist in concrete particulars.

Comment: Yes, it is numerical identity, see [IEP, Strong realism](https://iep.utm.edu/universa/#SH2b):"The universal red, for example, is in this apple, that apple, and all apples that are similarly red. It is not distinct and independent from the individuals that have this color. Because it is a universal it can exist in many places at once. According to Strong Realism, the universal red in my apple is numerically identical to the red in yours; one universal is in two individuals at once. It is wholly present in each place where it exists."

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to confirm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach to the philosophical problem of universals is to start with the following explanation about [universals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_universals):

> Platonic realism is the view that universals are real entities
> existing independent of particulars. Aristotelian realism, on the
> other hand, is the view that universals are real entities, but their
> existence is dependent on the particulars that exemplify them.

Plato and Aristole both agree that universals like “being beautiful” or “being just” resp. “beauty” or “justice” exist.

- According to Plato, the existence of the universal is ontologically
  first: The concrete objects (*particulars*) are beautiful because they
  particiate on the same primordial idea (*universal*) of beauty.
- According to Aristotle, first there exist concrete objects, then one
  can abstract from the different particulars to the abstract idea of
  beauty, being one of the common properties of the particulars.

Correspondingly one can name Plato’s approach *top-down*, while Aristole’s approach is *bottom-up*.

Comment: Under aristotelian realism, is there a single universal that exists in several particulars? Meaning the universal redness in apple A is numerically identical to the redness in apple B. Meaning can a single universal exist at multiple spatiotemporal locations?Or are there several universals of redness, each distinct from the other, indiscernible and numerically more than one?

Comment: @AbdulRehmanMohsin There is only one universal redness. The universal greenness is a second, different universal. Universals do not exist in spacetime, they are ideas.

Comment: "Universals do not exist in space-time, they are ideas". But isn't that nominalism? Under moderate realism, universals exist *in* the particulars, so they must exist in space-time no?

Comment: @AbdulRehmanMohsin Nominalism denies the existence of universals. But the whole subject and its ramification in the history of philosophy is too extended to fit in the few lines of a comment. I recommend https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nominalism-metaphysics/ and https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/universals-medieval/ and to post a resulting separate question with a single focus.

Comment: "nominalism denies the existence of universals" that is exactly what I'm trying to understand. If each instance of the universal redness is numerically identical to every other instance of it under moderate realism, then it is true that nominalism denies universals. However, if universals are distinct in each particular, and there is no numerical identity of each redness under moderate realism, then there seems to be no difference between nominalism and moderate realism. The first website, by the way, says that under aristotelian or in re realism, universals do exist spatiotemporally.